# How to add a different background color in my active button?

Tags: css, background

I'm trying to give a different background-color to my button when it is active. The HTML code is as below.

```
<div class="tabs">
<div class="tab-content">

<div id="tab1" class="tab active">
<!-- some content -->
</div>

<div id="tab2" class="tab">
<!-- some content -->
 </div>

 <div id="tab3" class="tab">
 <!-- some content -->
 </div>

 <ul class="tab-links">
 <li class="active">
 <a href="#tab1"><span class="numer_viti">bla bla</span>
 <p class="arrow-up"><p class="cmimet_ne_vite">BUTTON ACTIVE</p></p></a>
 </li>
 <li>
 <a href="#tab2"><span class="numer_viti">bla bla</span>
 <p class="arrow-up"><p class="cmimet_ne_vite">BUTTON</p></p></a>
 </li>
 <li>
 <a href="#tab3"><span class="numer_viti">bla bla</span>
 <p class="arrow-up"><p class="cmimet_ne_vite">BUTTON</p></p></a>
 </li>
 </ul> 

 </div>
 </div>
```

I used both this codes in my CSS files and i didn't sow nothing happened:

This is the CSS code for my project:

```
.cmimet_ne_vite:active
{
 background:#787878;
}

.cmimet_ne_vite.active
{
 background:#787878;
}
```

So who knows were is the problem to help me resolve it?

Comment: you try focus ? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/exmLusw1/

Answer (score 0):

You have no element with both classes "cmimet_ne_vite" **and** "active". Instead you have a `.cmimet_ne_vite` element which is a **descendant** of your `.active` element, so instead of `.cmimet_ne_vite.active` you'll need to use:

```css
.active .cmimet_ne_vite {
    background:#787878;
}
```

Furthermore, you cannot wrap two `<p>` elements within each other. The browser will render this as two separate elements. Change:

```
<p class="arrow-up">
    <p class="cmimet_ne_vite">BUTTON</p>
</p>
```

To:

```
<p class="arrow-up">
    <span class="cmimet_ne_vite">BUTTON</span>
</p>
```

Or something similar.

Finally, if this element is intended to be used as a button you'll need to give it a `role` attribute set to "button":

```
<span class="cmimet_ne_vite" role="button">BUTTON</span>
```